# NativeScript: XML template to HTML

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm new to NativeScript and I'm working on a NativeScript application with TypeScript, Angular, and HTML.

I want to use [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-chatview) in my application.
I've installed the plugin successfully and encountered no error and `tns run android` ran successfully.
In documentation, they have defined the way to use it in XML way:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
      xmlns:chatView="nativescript-chatview"
      navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">

  <chatView:ChatView id="myChatView" />
</Page>
```

But I need to implement this in HTML form,
and I've tried it this way but it didn't work.

```
<ChatView id="myChatView"></ChatView>
```

My NativeScript version: 4.1.2.

Please tell me what it that I'm not seeing or missed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to convert the XML to HTML. The GUI in Nativescript is always programmed XML like you did in the first example, never in HTML. Do you want to use this plugin on a normal webpage without nativescript? This will not work.

Comment: @FireGnome this is not true, Angular allows HTML definitions. So the XML definition from "NativeScript Core" is not valid and there should be an HTML definition.

Comment: The plugin is outdated but do check this blog post https://www.nativescript.org/blog/create-a-realtime-chat-interface-with-firebase-and-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this plugin has not been updated since one year, so there is no support for NativeScript 4, anyway there is no support for NativeScript Angular in this plugin.

The best for you is to create your own component for the chat. A complete, concrete, NativeScript+Angular example is available here: https://github.com/Especializa/nativescript-whatsapp-template